# SEO friendly ajax driven websites

Tags: php, ajax, seo

I have created an ajax driven website which can load any page when given the correct parameters. For instance: www.mysite.com/?page=blog&id=7 opens a blog post.

If I create a sitemap with links to all pages within the website will this be indexed?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you put it in an anchor tag, the search engines will follow the link. But if you redirect with javaScript, it won't be able to check after it. Choose a technique. =)

Comment: As a note, it is usually better to test something out first before asking a question here, bit difficult with this of course, but for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide a url for each page that will actually display the full page, then yes. If those requests are just responding with JSON, or only part of a page, then no. In reality this is probably a poor design SEO wise. Each page should have it's own URL e.g. `www.mysite.com/unicorns` instead of `www.mysite.com/?page=blog&id=1`, and the links on the page should point to those. Then you should be using Javascript to capture all the link click events for the AJAX links, and then use Javascript how you like to update the page. Or better yet maybe try out [PJAX](http://pjax.heroku.com/) which will load just the content of a page instead of a full page refresh speeding things up a little without really any changes from your normal site setup.

Comment: Also, if you submit an XML sitemap to Google using the [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) then Google will index what you tell it too. Learn more about XML Sitemaps [here](http://www.sitemaps.org/) and [here](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html).

Comment: Cool thanks. I will split the full URL and calculate page from there.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that making that sitemap all your search engine links will be ugly.

As [Google said](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) a page can still be crawled with nice url if you use `fragment identifier`:

```
 <meta name="fragment" content="!"> // for meta fragment
```

and when you generate your page by ajax append the fragment to URL:

```
 www.mysite.com/#!page=blog-7 //(and split them)
```

The page should load content directly in PHP by using `$_GET['_escaped_fragment_']`

As I've read that Bing and Yahoo started crawling with same [process](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started).